# How to get Average from DOW of Date column using crossfilter to populate in bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Iam working in Crossfilter with dc.js,

i have to get Average of Units for each day of week in bar chart.
i have date and units column and i have tried getting DOW(Dayofweek) from Date and with that DOW i tried getting average of the Units, but not working.
i have attached my code here, please help me out.

```
        d3.csv("LargeCSVFile.txt", function (error, data) {
                var dayOfWeekChart = dc.barChart("#dc2");
                var dateFormat = d3.time.format('%m/%d/%Y');
                var ndx = crossfilter(data);
                var all = ndx.groupAll();

                var dayOfWeek = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                    var dateval = dateFormat.parse(d.Date);
                    var day = dateval.getDay();                       
                    return day;
                });

                var AVGUnitsDimGroup = dayOfWeek.group().reduce(
                //add
                function (p, v) {
                   ++p.count;

                    p.sum = v.Units;
                    p.avg = p.sum / p.count;
                    return p;
                },
                //remove
                function (p, v) {
                    --p.count;

                    p.sum = v.Units;
                    p.avg = p.sum / p.count;
                    return p;
                },
                //init
                function (p, v) {
                    return {
                        count: 0,                            
                        avg: 0,
                        sum: 0
                    };
                });

                dayOfWeekChart.width(180)
                .height(180)
                .margins({ top: 20, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20 })                   
                .dimension(dayOfWeek)
                .group(AVGUnitsDimGroup)
                .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0.5, 7.5]))
                .label(function (d) {
                    return d.key;
                })
                .title(function (d) {
                    return d.value.avg;
                })                                          
                .elasticX(true)                        
                .xAxis().ticks(4);
                 dc.renderAll();
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it myself, I forgot to add the sum values and adding .valueAccessor(function (p) {
                        return p.value.avg;
                    }) next to group function made my code to work properly. here is my working code.

```
               d3.csv("LargeCSVFile.txt", function (error, data) {
                var dayOfWeekChart = dc.barChart("#dc2");

                 data.forEach(function (d) {
                    d.dd = new Date(d.Date);
                });

                var ndx = crossfilter(data);
                var all = ndx.groupAll();

                var dayOfWeek = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                    return d.dd.getDay();
                });

                 var AVGUnitsDimGroup = dayOfWeek.group().reduce(
                //add
                function (p, v) {
                    ++p.count;
                    p.sum += v.Units / 1;
                    p.avg = p.sum / p.count;
                    return p;
                },
                //remove
                function (p, v) {
                    --p.count;
                    p.sum += v.Units / 1;
                    p.avg = p.sum / p.count;
                    return p;
                },
                //init
                function (p, v) {
                    return {
                        count: 0,
                        sum: 0,
                        avg: 0
                    };
                });


                dayOfWeekChart.width(400)
                .height(300)
                .margins({ top: 20, left: 50, right: 10, bottom: 20 })
                .transitionDuration(1500)
                .dimension(fluctuation)
                .group(AVGUnitsDimGroup)
                .valueAccessor(function (p) {
                    return p.value.avg;
                })
                .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
                .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
                .title(function (d) {
                    return d.value.avg;
                })
                .xAxisPadding(600)
                .elasticX(true)
                .elasticY(true)
                .xAxis().ticks();

                dc.renderAll();
           })
```